# Having trouble using IterTools package in Julia after installation

Tags: package, julia, python-itertools

I am new to Julia, and I need to make use of some perks of the `IterTools.jl` package.
I installed it with:

> `using Pkg`
>
> `Pkg.add("IterTools")`

It seemed as though the installation of the package worked.

However, whenever I try to use any of the functions from the package, I get an error.
For instance:

```
for i in partition(1:9, 3)
    @show i
end
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: partition not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

I didn't have any similar problems with any other packages I tried installing.
I tried updating the packages, restarting the REPL and removing and reinstalling the package. None of it worked and I end up with the same problem.

I'd appreciate help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to load the package:

```
using IterTools
```